# windows installer service could not be started

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm on windows 7 64 bit, i'm using the admin accouunt, i try to install some programs, but can't, i troubleshooted the error that i got, and turned out that windows installer service is stopped, i tried to start it, it says

`windows installer service could not be started because its disabled or it has no enabled devices associated with it. Error 1058`

How to fix it?

Note that the laptop has an expired bitdefender installed on it. I don't know if it's causing the problem or not, i just thought it was worth mentioning since i had many problems with misconfigured or expired antiviruses before.

The `MSIServer` could not be started as well, and i tried to `run as administrator`

The laptop is not mine, i'm just trying to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps, from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241584/):

1. Click `Start`, type `Services` in the Search box, and then click `Services`.
2. Scroll until you find the service that is stopped or disabled.
3. Click the `Log On As` tab.
4. If the service is listed as disabled for your profile, right-click the service, and then click `Properties`.

   [image]
5. Click the `Startup type` list, and then click `Automatic`.
6. Click `Apply`, and then click `OK`.

Comment: Just curious, why would we want to start MSIServer automatically on boot?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have administrator access to the machine, I'd suggest you follow [959894](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959894) and install either the [32-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ad724ae0-e72d-4f54-9ab3-75b8eb148356&displaylang=en) or [64-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=585D2BDE-367F-495E-94E7-6349F4EFFC74) version of Malicious Software Removal Tool (MSRT) depending on your machine configuration.

It is important to be reasonably confident that your machine is not compromised though as you mentioned an expired Bit Defender. If you would rather not use MSRT,  kb 959894 also lists how you can get into safe mode to use other tools. Then, assuming everything goes well and you can reasonably say that your machine is not infected, [kb 241584](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241584) has you covered as you can see in [Tiago](https://superuser.com/a/627199/20687)'s answer.

Click Start, type Services in the Search box, and then click Services.

1. Scroll until you find the service that is stopped or disabled. [image: Start menu]
2. Click the Log On As tab. Is MSIServer set to run as Local System? [image: Credentials for MSIServer]
3. Try to start Windows Installer manually. [image: Services screen before] [image: Services screen after]

Local System account should already have full access to your system. In case you are not able to start MSI Server at this point, the integrity of your system is in question. Try running [System File Checker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) with `/scannow` argument.

1. go to start and type cmd. right click and choose run as administrator. [image: run as admin]
2. type in `sfc /scannow` and hit enter. [image: sfc]

Learn more about the sfc tool at [kb 929833](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

Answer (score 3):

If options to enable or disable service is dimmed/grey:

In an elevated command prompt on the server, execute the following. (Note: reboot will be required).

Replace SERVICENAME

1) If `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SERVICENAME /v Start` value is currently 0x4, change it to 0x3 by entering the following command:
`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SERVICENAME /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3`
Enter "Yes" to confirm the change

2) Verify the value is now set to 0x3
`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SERVICENAME /v Start`

3) Reboot

4) You should now be able to start the service.

Comment: Finally a working solution to my problem